# A plane curve which is nowhere an embedding

Tags: general-topology

Is there a continuous map $\gamma \colon [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ which satisfies the following?

1. "Moves and never looks back": $\gamma(0) = (0,0)$ and $\gamma(t) \neq (0,0)$ when $t \neq 0$.
2. "Is never simple": there is no choice of $0\leq a < b \leq 1$ making the restriction $\gamma|_{[a,b]}$ injective.

I suspect the answer is "yes" just because otherwise would be too good to be true in the wild world of curves.

Comment: Can't you take $\gamma(t) = (f[t]-f[0], 0)$ for $f$ a Weierstrass function?

Comment: user7530 has reduced the problem to finding a function $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ having the desired properties.

Comment: Another idea is to consider space filling curves. However, the usual examples do not satisy 1.